# How to use epic editor on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to using javascript on rails and I want to have an interface such that on a view, a user can type, using markdown, into a textarea and the output should be updated according to the markdown syntax as the user continues to type. I found epic editor as a solution and I created an epiceditor.js file in my assets/javascripts and in my model's js.coffee file i have

```
editor = new EpicEditor().load()
```

However, I don't know how to render a input textarea and the output in the same view with epic editor? Can someone please give me some guidance? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just started working with epiceditor in combination with rails and this is what I've got so far:

Change the basePath and theme, preview, editor paths.

```
defaults = { container: 'epiceditor'
    , basePath: '/assets'
    , textarea: 'content-input'
    , clientSideStorage: true
    , localStorageName: 'epiceditor'
    , useNativeFullscreen: true
    , file: { name: null
    , defaultContent: ''
      , autoSave: 100 // Set to false for no auto saving
      }
    , theme: { base: '/epiceditor.css'
      , preview: '/github.css'
      , editor: '/epic-style.css'
      }
```

If you use the simple_form gem you can add this to your forms:

```
<%= f.input :content, label: false, input_html: {id: "content-input"}, as: :hidden%>
<div id="epiceditor"></div>
```

then in your epiceditor.js file change textarea to textarea: 'content-input' (the textarea id) so that it will sync with the hidden textarea.

```
function EpicEditor(options) {
// Default settings will be overwritten/extended by options arg
var self = this
  , opts = options || {}
  , _defaultFileSchema
  , _defaultFile
  , defaults = { container: 'epiceditor'
    , basePath: '/assets'
    , textarea: 'content-input'
    , clientSideStorage: true
    , localStorageName: 'epiceditor'
    , useNativeFullscreen: true
    , file: { name: null
```

The default sync/export is text, to change that set it to 'html'

```
_syncTextarea = function () {
  self._textareaElement.value = self.exportFile(textareaFileName, 'html', true) || self.settings.file.defaultContent;
}
```

and load the script ofcourse

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var editor = new EpicEditor().load();
</script>
```